# Why is an HTML element taking up far more space than it should be?

Tags: html, css

I have a little bit of text on a page that I am placing using CSS.

This is the `div` class:

```
<div id="alpha">
Alpha
</div>
```

This is the CSS that I am using to position it:

```
#alpha {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 72px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

The problem is that that CSS causes the whole page to be wide. Before that code, you could not scroll horizontally in the browser. Now that I added that CSS (and I have isolated it to that specific CSS) the browser allows for scrolling to the right as if there was some invisible image that was protruding all the way to the right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was going to add, the width is the entire width of its parent element, or page if no parent is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a div is a block element; the width will be the entire page width unless you give it a width.

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GnKnf/)

links to js fiddle must be accompanied with code.  Here is a code block.
`<code>hoot</code>`

Answer (score 1):

try to add `overflow: hidden` to your `body` style.

`div` is 100% wide, so when you move it to the right it does not fit in the window anymore, that's why you are getting scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
#alpha {
    margin-bottom: 72px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```